# Erro em paginação dentro da aba

Tags: javascript, paginação, aba

Estou com um problema estranho, em certa parte do meu site eu tenho uma aba, só que dentro de uma delas existe uma paginação, que quando foi colocada dentro da aba não funcionava e só aparecia os botões previous e next mas não os das páginas. Então eu implementei um código em javascript que quando clicava nesta aba específica realizava ele, ai a paginação apareceu com as duas páginas de teste, só que ai surgiu outro problema, pois quando eu vou pra outra aba e volto para a da paginação só aparece número 1 como se tivesse só uma página e eu não consegui entender pq raios isso acontece, então recorri a vcs, colocarei todos os códigos que estou usando abaixo.

**Para paginação estou o usando o plugin JPAGES**
[JPAGES LINK](http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/pagination.html)

**HTML ABA + PAGINAÇÃO**

```
<div class="tabs-media">
<!--aba-->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#media-1">media1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#media-2">media3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#media-3" class="press">media3</a></li> <!--CLASS PRESS UTILIZADA PARA INTRODUZIR PAGINAÇÃO-->
</ul>

<!--conteudo da aba-->
<section id="media-1">
    conteudo1
</section>

<section id="media-2">
    CONTEUDO 2
</section>

<section id="media-3"> <!--ABA ONDE É INSERIDA A PAGINAÇÃO-->
    <div id="content"> <!--ID CONTENT INDICA ONDE FICA O CONTEÚDO DA PAGINAÇÃO-->
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque erat at neque pretium dapibus.. </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="pagination">
        <a href="#" class="jp-previous" title="PREVIOUS">PREVIOUS</a>
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
        <a href="#">6</a>
        <a href="#">7</a>
        <a href="#">8</a>
        <a href="#">9</a>
        <a href="#">10</a>
        <a href="#" class="jp-next" title="NEXT">NEXT</a>           
    </nav>
</section>
```

**CÓDIGOS JAVASCRIPT**

**CONFIGURAÇÃO DAS TABS**

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".tabs-media" ).tabs();
  } );
</script>
```

**CONFIGURAÇÃO DA PAGINAÇÃO AO CLICAR NA 3 ABA**

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".press").click(function(){
            $(".pagination").jPages({
                containerID  : "content",
                previous     : "PREVIOUS",
                next         : "NEXT",
                perPage      : 10,
                startPage    : 1,
                startRange   : 1,
                midRange     : 5,
                endRange     : 1
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Poderá ser por já estar definido o jPages (não testei). Experimente:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".press").on('click',function(){
        if ($(".pagination").jPages()) {
            $(".pagination").jPages("destroy");
        }
        $(".pagination").jPages({
            containerID  : "content",
            previous     : "PREVIOUS",
            next         : "NEXT",
            perPage      : 10,
            startPage    : 1,
            startRange   : 1,
            midRange     : 5,
            endRange     : 1
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

para colocar isso ao seleccionar a tab penso que será assim:

```
$('.tabs-media').tabs({
   select: function(event, ui){
     var myTabIndex = 3; // indice da tab a executar
     if(ui.index == myTabIndex ) {
       if ($(".pagination").jPages()) {
          $(".pagination").jPages("destroy");
       }
       $(".pagination").jPages({
          containerID  : "content",
          previous     : "PREVIOUS",
          next         : "NEXT",
          perPage      : 10,
          startPage    : 1,
          startRange   : 1,
          midRange     : 5,
          endRange     : 1
       });
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: vou tentar aqui vlw

Comment: Perfeito a primeira opção funcionou, queria perguntar se tem como fazer isso quando clica na aba ao invés de só fazer isso no botão press, pq ai eu só coloco um código javascript pra todas paginações do site? Vou editar no seu código como é o original

Comment: Editei na minha resposta como poderá fazer ao clicar na tab

Comment: coloquei esta sua forma editada e acontece que agora ao invés de aparecer só dois registros na paginação, aparece 10, e não dá pra clicar em nenhuma delas